# How to show array elements on listbox selecteditem ? c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

i would like to get array elements on listbox selectedindex.
Also it shows what excatly found array elements but it doesnt select first element of array on listbox

> Listbox = cbx_dekor_paneli

```
    string[] dekordizisi;
    void listedendekoral()
    {
        dekordizisi = Sipariş_Listesi_Güncelle.dekorgonder.ToString().Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < dekordizisi.Count(); i++)
        {
            cbx_dekor_paneli.SelectedIndex = 
            cbx_dekor_paneli.FindString(dekordizisi[i].ToString());

            //already tried that one
            //cbx_dekor_paneli.SelectedItem = dekordizisi[i].ToString();
        }

    }
```

> Listbox items add from mysql

```
        void DB_dekor()
    {
        db.vtbaslat();
        vtbaglan();
        try
        {
            cbx_dekor_paneli.Items.Clear();
            //dekorlar
            MySqlCommand listegor = new MySqlCommand("select * from dekor order by dekor_id asc", db.baglanti);
            MySqlDataReader liste = listegor.ExecuteReader();
            while (liste.Read())
            {
                cbx_dekor_paneli.Items.Add(liste["dekor_kod"].ToString());
            }
            liste.Close();
            listegor.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception hata)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(hata.Message);
        }
    }
```

> Update

I made a mistake on my database. some values had spaces.
Also i prefer to **Selection Mode: MultiSimple** Solve with that code

```
        cbx_dekor_paneli.ClearSelected();
        dekordizisi = Sipariş_Listesi_Güncelle.dekorgonder.ToString().Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < dekordizisi.Count(); i++)
        {
            cbx_dekor_paneli.SelectedIndex = cbx_dekor_paneli.FindStringExact(dekordizisi[i].ToString());
        }
```

thanks for [@Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) and [@yassinMi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19399896/yassinmi) to help me.

Comment: Did you add the items to `cbx_dekor_paneli`?

Comment: cbx_dekor_paneli is my listbox name, thats my fault, doesnt tagged that, and yes im added items on listbox

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to select multiple items on the ListBox based on the content of the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dekordizisi.Count(); i++)
    {
        cbx_dekor_paneli.SetSelected(cbx_dekor_paneli.FindString(dekordizisi[i]), true);
    }
```

Also make sure the `ListBox.SelectionMode` Property is set to `MultiExtended`

Comment: it gives Exception Unhandled error
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument='-1'
Parametername: index'

Comment: it looks like some of the items in dekordizisi array doesn't exist on the ListBox

Comment: listbox didnt get first element of array, thats the my problem, it was from beginning

Comment: Just call `SetSelected()` when `.FindString()` returns a non-negative value (i.e., assign the return value to a local variable and test it). -- Call the `ClearSelected()` method of the ListBox beforehand.

Comment: i used tester string with "1" value
it shows listbox.items[1], it doesnt find my string

Answer (score 0):

May this helps you with your code.

```
string dekordizisi = [];
foreach(int i in dekordizisi.GetSelectedIndices())
{
  dekordizisi = dekordizisi + dekordizisi.Items[i] + ",";
}
dekordizisi = dekordizisi.Remove(dekordizisi.Length - 1);
```

in this code we are initializing a variable "dekordizisi" to an array and then with foreach we are adding it inside the array.

Comment: im getting my label value from another form like 2,3,18
and doing split to adding inside string array, so converting to my label value to array

Comment: im trying to shows them on listbox selecteditem